# Add-in manifest uploaded in organization App catalog does not come up

Tags: office-js, office-addins

We have a office-365 online tenant  for our organization. I have created an App catalog for the tenant based on the instructions provided in this link https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/set-up-an-add-in-catalog-on-office-365.

I uploaded some new Add-in manifest files in the catalog. However the new Add-ins do not come up immediately in the organization catlog for the desktop clients. The manifest are valid and when I test then using the Sideloading of Add-ins it works fine.

Can someone shed some light on why the new Add-ins do not come up in the catalog ?

I am the admin of the tenant and have full contribute permissions. So i don't think this is a permission issue.

Comment: I finally figured the issue. Manifests with Add-in commands are not supported in Sharepoint Catalog.Found the information in this link https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-commands

Answer (score 0):

I actually experienced a similar issue.  When you side load the add-in it doesn't do a full validation.

I know of two ways to do the full validation.  One is to grab the latest XSD and do a validation in your preferred xml schema validator tool.  In addition to that you could try to submit it to the app store (you don't have to complete the submission as it validates the schema when you drop the manifest in the first step).

Some gotchas that aren't obvious right off the bat.  Element order matters in the manifest.  Also Resource Ids have a short character limit of 30-35.  In most example manifests "Contoso" will get in under the limit but if you trade that for something much longer you'll be over it.

Addins with schema validation errors won't show in add-in catalogs but will side load successfully.